# Loop within loops vba

Tags: vba, loops, bloomberg

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that could execute a BDH bloomberg code for each equity and within each equity id want it to go through all of the criteria such as "PX_Last", VOL_90D, PX_BID and etc.

Essentially, the ideal output I'd like would be:

Eg:

```
0665 HK Equity -> PX_Last, PX_BID, PX_ASK, VOL_90D, then, 
1098 HK Equity -> PX_Last, PX_BID, PX_ASK, VOL_90D, then,
```

etc.

Here is a code that I've recently created for my spreadsheet.

Would appreciate any insights about my code!

```
For x = 1 To i
   If x = 1 Then
    equity = Worksheets(1).Cells(x + 2, 2)
    Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value = equity
        For y = 1 To j
            If y = 1 Then
                reutersticker = Worksheets(1).Cells(y + 2, 1)
                Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = reutersticker   
                    For Z = 1 To k
                        If Z = 1 Then
                            LastPrice = Worksheets(1).Cells(Z + 1, 8)
                            Worksheets(2).Cells(3, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(""" & equity & """," & LastPrice & ",""" & StartDate & """,""" & EndDate & """," & Weekdays & "," & Fill & ")"    
                        ElseIf Z > 1 Then
                            LastPrice = Worksheets(1).Cells(Z + 1, 8)
                            Worksheets(2).Cells(3, 1).Offset(, (2 * Z) - 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=BDH(""" & equity & """," & LastPrice & ",""" & StartDate & """,""" & EndDate & """," & Weekdays & "," & Fill & ")"
                        End If                      
                    Next Z                      
            ElseIf y > 1 Then             
                reutersticker = Worksheets(1).Cells(y + 2, 1)
                Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Offset(, (4 * y) - 2).Value = reutersticker
            End If          
         Next y          
    ElseIf x > 1 Then    
       equity = Worksheets(1).Cells(x + 2, 2)        
       Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Offset(, (8 * x) - 2).Value = equity
    End If 
  Next x  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you hving any issues with the code? or just looking to make it more efficient?